# str function does not return the the digits after decimal point

Tags: r, string

I am working with a dataset and one of my variables that is numeric contains values with digits until millionths point (e.g., 4273.453214). when I run str on this variable, it only returns the digits before the decimal point.

```
str(l03$SOC)
 num [1:3316] 4273 4273 4273 4273 4273
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

I tried "sprintf" and "options" functions but they did not work

Comment: Read [`?str`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html), and read about `digits.d`. Compare `str(data.frame(a=4273.453214))` with `str(data.frame(a=4273.453214), digits.d=10)`.